# User tabs for anonymous users

Tags: users, routes

The user tabs are:

View

Edit

My content (created with Views with path user/%/track)

Every user can edit his profile with the user tab "Edit".
When registered user enters other profile the two tabs "View" and "My content" are available, without "edit" (that's fine), but what about anonymous users?

When I enter from anonymous user into /user/1/track I see the content but without the tabs(View and My content).

How can I make these tabs displayed from anonymous users?

Do I have to use hook_menu_alter for this core element?

EDIT:
"View user profiles" is already activated for anonymous users in permissions page and **user/1** and **user/%/track** are accessible for anonymous users, but the tabs are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I forgot that that I've deactivated the .tabs-wrapper with CSS for the anonymous users. hook_menu_local_tasks_alter and krumo helped me to solve out that the access of the tabs is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission issue. Simply enable the permission **"View user profiles"** for anonymous users.

Comment: "View user profiles" is already activated for anonymous users in permissions page.